# Faster way to remove 2TB of data from single collection (without sharding)

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

We collect a lot of data and currently decided to migrate our data from mongodb into data lake. We are going to leave in mongo only some portion of our data and use it as our operational database that keeps only newest most relevant data. We have replica set, but we don't use sharding. I suspect, if we had sharded cluster, we could achieve necessary results much simpler, but it's one-time operation, so setting up cluster just for one operation looks like very complex solution (plus I also suspect, that it will be very long running operation to convert such collection into sharded collection, but I can be completely wrong here)

One of our collections has size of 2TB right now. We want to remove old data from original database as fast as possible, but looks like standard "remove" operation is very slow, even if we use unorderedBulkOperation.

I found a few suggestions to copy data into another collection and then just drop original collection instead of trying remove data (so migrate data that we want to keep instead of removing data that we don't want to keep). There are few different ways, that I found, to copy portion of data from original collection to another collection:

1. Extract data and insert it into other collection one by one. Or extract portion of data and insert it in bulk using insertMany(). It looks faster than just remove data, but still not enough fast.
2. Use $out operator with aggregation framework to extract portions of data. It's very fast! But it extracts every portion of data into separate collections and doesn't have ability to append data in current mongodb version. So we will need to combine all exported portions of data into one final collection, what is slow again. I see that $out will be able to append data in next release of mongo (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12280). But we need some solution now, and unfortunately, we won't be able to do quick update of mongo version anyway.
3. mongoexport / mongoimport - it exports portion of data into json file and append to another collection using import. It's quite fast too, so looks like good option.

Currently it looks like the best choice to improve performance of migration is combination of $out + mongoexport/mongoimport approaches. Plus multithreading to perform multiple described operations at once.

But is there any even faster option that I might missed?

Comment: I don't think there's a faster way other than the three you have mentioned. This is because the operation is bottlenecked in disk performance, and the amount of data involved is relatively large. However, since this is a one-off operation, I would suggest you to go with the "safest" option. That is, a method that you are familiar with and have the least chance of failure. Importantly, if it failed, you know how to restart it reliably.